# Django Tags results pagination not working as I expected

Tags: python, django, pagination

I'm trying to paginate the results I get back from my tags, but it's not working right. If I have three posts, the paginator will make have three results pages, if I have two posts, the paginator will have two results pages. How ever many posts I have Thats how many pages the paginator will have. The paginator works if I use it to return normal results from the database. What I did was copy it and try to modify it to suit the tags paginations. But it's not working as I expected. I also put the pagination in an includes file, trying to keep things DRY, and I'm not sure if that me be the issue here's my code.

pagination.html:

```
<div class="text-center" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
<ul class="pagination">
{% if queryset.has_previous %}
    <li><a href="?page=1"><<</a></li>
    <li><a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.previous_page_number }}
{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">prev</a></li>
{% endif %}


{% for i in paginator.page_range %}

 <li {% if page_obj.number == i %} class="active" {% endif %}><a href="?page={{i}}">{{i}}</a><li>
<!--Page {{ queryset.number }} of {{ queryset.paginator.num_pages }}.-->

{% endfor %}


{% if queryset.has_next %}
    <li><a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.next_page_number }}
    {% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">next</a></li>
    <li><a href="?page={{ queryset.paginator.num_pages }}">>></a></li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
```

this pagination does not work how I want it to views.py:

```
def tag_list(request, slug=None):
instance = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=slug)
ins = instance.post_set.all()

query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    ins = ins.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(content__icontains=query) |
            Q(user__first_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(user__last_name__icontains=query)
    ).distinct()

paginator = Paginator(ins, 1)
page_request_var = "page"
page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
try:
    queryset = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    queryset = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

context = {
    "instance": ins,
    "queryset": queryset,
    "paginator": paginator,

}
return render(request, "posts/tag_list.html", context)
```

the following is where I copied pagination. This one works

```
def post_list(request):
today = timezone.now().date()
queryset_list = Post.objects.active()
if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
    queryset_list = Post.objects.all()

query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(content__icontains=query) |
            Q(user__first_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(user__last_name__icontains=query)
    ).distinct()
paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 6)  # Show 25 contacts per page
page_request_var = "page"
page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
try:
    queryset = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    queryset = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
context = {
        "queryset": queryset,
        "title": "Posts",
        "page_request_var": page_request_var,
        "today": today,
        "queryset_list": queryset_list,
        "paginator": paginator,
    }

return render(request, "posts/post_list.html", context)
```

Comment: What *isnt* working? Its unclear to me what the actual problem is

Comment: @Sayse the tags pagination. When I click a tag I want the user to be sent to the tags_list.html which will display all the post with the same tag. and If I can only show four per page and and have sixteen results, I want four pages to show in the paginator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of the paginator is how many results to show per page, currently you have it set to one, as per your comment, you probably want this to be 4

```
paginator = Paginator(ins, 1)
```

should be

```
paginator = Paginator(ins, 4)
```

---

You also never pass back the `page_request_var` to the template, which means it won't ever find the correct page, and then returns the same page

```
context = {
    "instance": ins,
    "queryset": queryset,
    "paginator": paginator,
    "page_request_var": page_request_var
}
```

Comment: This only works if I use it without the tags. The normal way. When I do it with the tags it doesn't work. If I have five posts and  make paginator like this, paginator = Paginator(ins, 1) I'm supposed to have five pages each with different results but instead I get 5\five pages with the same results

Comment: My posts have Tags. foer instance, If I click "action" all posts that have an action tag will show in my tags_list.html page. If I click "comedy" all comedies show up etc

Comment: @losee - See my last update re: missing context variable, I'm not sure what the issue is if it isn't that.